# Rails 3: Create multiple associated model records in single save statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an associations like:

```
class Contact
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :email_addresses
  has_many :phone_numbers
end
```

I want to save all the records (address, email and phones) in once single `save` statement. For that I wrote following code.

```
contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
contact.addresses.build(address_params1)
contact.addresses.build(address_params2)
contact.email_addresses.build(email_params1)
contact.email_addresses.build(email_params2)
contact.phone_numbers.build(phone_params1)
contact.phone_numbers.build(phone_params2)
contact.save
```

It does save the contact, but not saving other records. What am I missing here?

NOTE: I am not using any form to save data. I am importing data.

Comment: This is not a proper way to write a code, try `simple_form` http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form it will certainly help you

Comment: I agree Salil, this should be done using `simple_form` but here I am importing contacts from Google.

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001667) in your `contact` model and then check

```
validates_associated :addresses, :email_addresses, :phone_numbers
```

Comment: Salil, its for validating associated records and not for saving.

Answer (score 0):

### First, In my opinion, you just CAN'T do that.

- If you want to save addresses, you need a contact_id for each of them.
- And, when you save contact, rails will first validate contact and all sub-objects. This means
  `contact.valid?` must be true before you can save any record.
- Since contact does not have an id before save to db, contact_id in any of addresses is empty.
  Therefore, `contact.valid?` will always be false as long as you need to **CREATE** new contact and its sub-objects at the same time
- To summarize, here is the steps of rails:

  1. validate contact itself, success!(NOTE: note saved)
  2. validate address for each of contact.addresses, contact_id not provided, fail!

### Second, my suggestion about your problem

About your problem "It does save the contact, but not saving other records.", you need to tell rails that you want to save sub-objects(as shown bellow). Otherwise, rails will ignore other objects. However, even though you did this, you would also meet the problem I described above.

```
#contact.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
...
```

My suggestion: you can use transaction.

1. creat contact
2. build all sub-objects
3. save contact again

code sample:

```
#contacts_controller.rb
Contact.transaction do
  contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  contact.addresses.build(address_params)
  ...
  contact.save
end
```